# How to copy the contents of File Loaded into a textBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, openfiledialog

I have a textbox and a button in my .xaml. When i click the button i am able to open a filedialog and able to select the file as well.

**MainWindow.Xaml:**

```
<TextBox Height="93" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Path=ReadMessage, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="MessageRead" />

<Button Content="Load" Name="I2CLoadBtn" Command={Binding Path = LoadContentCommand />
```

**My ViewModel Class:**

```
public static RelayCommand LoadContentCommand { get; set; }

    private string _ReadMessage;
    public string ReadMessage
    {
        get { return __ReadMessage; }
        set
        {
            __ReadMessage= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ReadMessage");
        }
    }

    private void RegisterCommands()
    {
        LoadContentCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ExecuteOpenFileDialog());
    }

    private void ExecuteOpenFileDialog()
    {
        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { InitialDirectory = _defaultPath };
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        dialog.DefaultExt = ".bin";
        dialog.Filter = "Bin Files (*.bin)|*.bin";           
    }
```

What i basically want is, once the file is selected, the contents of the file must be saved into the textbox. E.g. If I have a .txt file to be loaded, on loading the contents must get placed inside the textbox.

Please help!!!

Comment: sorry @OwaisWani, it seemed like you were using MVVM pattern,this doesn't mean that my answer was wrong though, my answer focus on loose coupling between classes so they can be better testable.

Comment: Thats k HichemC :) Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get the selected path:

```
string path = "";
if (dialog .ShowDialog() == true)
{
    path = dialog.FileName;
}

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
     ReadMessage = sr.ReadToEnd()
}
```

Comment: I got it. But I am confused where to put the FileReader class in my viewmodel class. can u help pls? :)

Comment: Dont put it into your ViewModel, just create a new class named FileReader in your solution.

Comment: Yes I tried and its working :) But the contents of text file are appearing in the form of 0 and 1's in my textbox. I want the textual data.

Comment: So you marked the post as answer which is just giving you the FileReader, which isnt even working right...seems legit. I edited my answer for you (using the StreamReader).

Comment: There you go. U helped me mate. Vote up + Ur answer is accepted :) God bless :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via an interface :

```
public interface IFileReader
    {
        string Read(string filePath);
    }
    public class FileReader : IFileReader
    {
        public string Read(string filePath)
        {
           byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(byte b in fileBytes)
            {
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));  
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Then you can instantiate this via you ViewModel's constructor or property :

```
  public ViewModel(IFileReader FileReader) // constructor
        { }

public IFileReader FileReader { get; set; } // property
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. How do i use the above code in my viewmodel class? can you elaborate the code based on binding titles I have given to my .xaml and viewmodel class?

Comment: you've done everything good so far, just you need to [inject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13831/Dependency-Injection-for-Loose-Coupling) FileReader to your ViewModel and use it in your `ExecuteOpenFileDialog()`

Comment: You wont necessarily need the interface, just create the class FileReader like shown above (without implementing the IFileReader-Interface) and make the method static (public static string Read(filePath)...). For the beginning I think this should be adequate. Now you can access the Read-Method without creating an instance of the FileReader like shown in my answer.

Comment: @HichemC If he just uses the FileReader to read a file (for this one method) where is the problem? Did you vote down my answer?

Comment: @FlorianGl Although you answer is correct,it encourages tight coupling.

Comment: @HichemC Ok, good to know. Can you describe in which way? I started programming one year ago, so I am not so deep in it and I would like to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I like the syntax of [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) for reading textfiles.

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
```